# how to use lambda to unpack this list [(a,b),(c,d),...] in python3

Tags: python, list, lambda

there. I want to use lambda function to unpack a list like this [(a,b),(c,d),...]
For example, now I have two lists like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

Then I can use zip function to generate a new list like this:

```
l = zip(list1,list2)
```

Here, `l = [(1,0.1),(2,0.2),(3,0.3)]`
And I want to do the operation on this list l like this:

```
outcome_l = [1*0.1, 2*0.2, 3*0.3]
```

As I know the easiest way is to define a lambda function looks like this:

```
f = lambda l1,l2:l1*l2
```

And then I may want to use this lambda function like this to get the outcome:

```
outcome_l = list(map(f,l))
```

But the problem in here is that it seems lambda function is hard to unpack every set in the list l, and it keeps saying me there exists an error as " < lambda > () takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given", that is the length of list l is 3.

So do you know how to deal with this problem in python3? It seems that python2 may not suffer the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f` (which, since you're naming it, you should've defined in the traditional way) takes two arguments. Each item in `l` is a single object - a tuple. The easiest way to solve this is with comprehensions, which are so versatile that they nearly prompted Python's designers to remove `map` from the language.

```
outcome_l = [a*b for a,b in l]
```

You could even use the function `f` in this manner, with `*` unpacking:

```
outcome_l = [f(*item) for item in l]
```

Comment: Probably no need for the OP to make the intermediate ```l``` and just use ```zip(...)```  in the comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `operator.mul` with your `map` to get your desired result. This function does the same thing as what you want. 
Taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) `map(mul, list1, list2)`

To make your function work you could use `f = lambda x: x[0] * x[1]`

Comment: `operator.mul` does the exact same thing as the OP's `f`, so you might want to mention that it's the different usage of `map` that makes it work.

Comment: Why this answer is down voted? Seems to me very strange to downvote answers like this one!

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [(1,0.1),(2,0.2),(3,0.3)]
outcome_l = [i*j for i, j in l]
```

or better:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
outcome_l = [i*j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```